# UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity returns multiple

Tags: wpf, active-directory, userprincipal

I need to validate a user with Active directory and check their groups.  Problem is that a user is returning multiple UserPrincipal.  Admins are unable to find the issue with this user. My code is straight forward;

```
var usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, username);
```

Now I know I could do this;

```
var usr = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
if (usr.IsInRole("MyRole")
{
   //Do stuff
}
```

That does work for the current user logged, however, there are times that I need to authentic a users that is not currently logged in

Comment: Is the user name definitely a user's name rather than an ad group? var usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);

Comment: @Andy The username, is the windows user login ID.

Comment: @Xaphann: Does `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), IdentityType.Name, username)` work? What's the exact value of `username` at runtime?

Comment: @mm8 It works for all users except one.  The AD admins are saying there is nothing wrong with this user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a system where I monitor recent account locks, using:

```
UserPrincipal.FindByLockoutTime(...)
```

I use this to give me a list of recently locked accounts.
I could click on the username to drill down into the details using:

```
UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userId)
```

I could see I had an account named Administrator, every time I clicked on it to drill down I was getting the same error:

> MultipleMatchesException

I discovered the FindByIdentity method accepts an overload for identity type which is an int:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.identitytype?view=netframework-4.8

As I knew I was querying by SamAccountName changing the method signature to:

```
UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, 0, userId)
```

Solved this issue for me.